# List assignment index out of range error - already assigned values

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, range

I have encountered a problem I don't really understand involving lists and indexes. Code follows:

```
listA = [-1 for i in range(1, 14)];

def functionA(num):
    for i in range (1, 14):
        listA[i] = num

functionA(1);
```

This gives me the 'IndexError: list assignment index out of range' message. I added in some print() statements in the space before functionA(1) to help debug, and found out that the loop is completing the iteration at listA[12], but failing when it reaches listA[13].

I had originally set the range(a, b) statements to end at 14 because I understood that that second parameter was not inclusive, and so should end at 13. How can it even try to write to the 13th index if the first line of code does not assign that index a value? Can somebody help/explain please?

Comment: Lists are 0-indexed.

Comment: Technically the first line of code doesn't assign *any* values into the list.

Comment: `for i in range (13)`

Comment: I know that lists are 0-indexed, but for my purposes (a card game) I choose to start the indexing at 1 so I can use their indexes as their point values as well, hence using range(1, 14) instead of range(13).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: It does, it just creates 13 `-1`s in a new `list` and assigns that `list` to the name `listA`.

Comment: Also, Ignacio, it does assign values to the list items, because I have put print(listA[1]); before running functionA(1); and it successfully prints -1 to console.

Comment: No, it creates a completely new list. It doesn't "assign" anything.

Comment: It's assigning into the new list, as long as we're making ridiculously pedantic arguments.

Comment: @HG-: Trying to ignore index 0 is just going to bite you. If you really want to only have "indices" that don't start at 0, you either have a base 0 `list` and `enumerate` it with a non-zero `start`, or you use a `dict`/`OrderedDict` where the keys can run from 1 to 13. Having garbage in the first index of a `list` breaks your ability to use native Python iteration of the list in a nice way, so you end up constantly using C-style iteration by index, and that's tying one hand behind your back.

Answer (score 0):

Python indices are base 0, not base 1. When you created the list, you used a `range(1, 14)` to loop, which means you only created 13 elements, from index 0 through 12 (you'd have gotten the exact same structure with `range(13)` because the value from `range` wasn't used, it was just controlling number of loops).

Since the indices run from 0 to 12 inclusive, when you later assign from 1 to 13 (because you looped on `range(1, 14)`), 0 remains unassigned, and you try to assign index 13, which is out of bounds.

Comment: Ah I see - I thought that using range(1, 14) instead of range(13) would start the indexing from 1, but I see that it starts it at 0 anyway. I see that I need to change the first line to range(14). Thanks